# Pandas str extract Month and Date from multiple text in a row

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that has long texts per row and clueless to extract month and date.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'country':['ALB'],
                      'response':["""*April, 1: Creation of a Joint Task Force. 
                                     * March, 21: The BCEAO announced initiating negotiations with firms issuing electronic money to encourage its usage to avoid cash use for hygiene reasons."""]})
```

I would like to get only month and date part from the above in the dataframe as

```
'April, 1', 'March, 21'
```

I tried the following code but no success:

```
df['date'] = df['response'].str.extract('(* March,)')
```

Appreciate your kind help.

Comment: _I tried with code str.extract but no success._ Can you show that code? This is quite broad.

Comment: df['date'] = df['response'].str.extract('(\* March,)')

Comment: How much do you know about regex? Again, this is too broad. Depending on how the dates appear in the text this task can get quite complex. Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use regular expressions

```
import re
df['month'] = [re.findall("\*(.*):",df.response[0])]
```

and the output of df['month'] is

```
['April, 1', ' March, 21']
```

Comment: I have follow up question. How do you put the answer in a column in the same dataframe

Comment: Have edited my answer to assign the result to a column

Comment: `df['date'] = df['response'].str.findall('\*(.*):')`

Comment: This is giving me a column but with a serie type format. But I want just simple text such as April, 1; March, 21. Is it possible to do that. You advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

`str.extract` gives you only one match. You need `extract all`:

```
df.response.str.extractall('(April|March), (\d+)')
```

Output:

```
             0   1
  match           
0 0      April   1
  1      March  21
```

Comment: You answer:  df['datePerse'] = df.response.str.extractall('(April|March), (\d+)') gives me the following error "incompatible index of inserted column with frame index"